# How to make the comment author name required for anonymous users?

Tags: 8, comments

I'm trying to make the comment author name required with this code:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MODULE_form_comment_comment_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['name']['#required'] = true;
}
```

But I can't find the way to do so. How to make the comment author name required for anonymous users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
  $form['author']['name']['#required'] = TRUE;
}
```

It is necessary because it is not right to check if user is authenticated by checking if the name field is prefilled.

We have to use `\Drupal::currentUser()` service in theme or module file (in controller you have to use `Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy`).

[currentUser() Documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AcurrentUser/8.2.x)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */

function MODULE_form_comment_comment_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) 
{
  if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
    $form['author']['name']['#required'] = TRUE;
  }
  else {
    $form['author']['name']['#required'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd argue that the if check is unnecessary - if the user is logged in the name field is prefilled anyway making the method proposed by Adrian marginally quicker.

Comment: As a note for this - I'm saying it's essentially redundant to check that the user is logged in as if they are logged in the required field is prefilled. With that said @AndrewNim's method is probably a more "Drupal" method of doing this. Plus a possibly-redundant if is preferrable to an error.

Answer (score 10):

I found the answer:

Implementing the `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` hook you can use the comment form id (`comment_comment_form`) to alter the form.

The problem was that the field name is inside the author, so you need to use `$form['author']['name']['#required'] = TRUE;`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MODULE_form_comment_comment_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['author']['name']['#required'] = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I edit the answer, if you see any problem feel free to edit.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer your edits look good to me - the explanation does make it clearer.

Comment: @HomoTechsual thanks, if you want edit the answer feel free too